# Javascript - Get text value from select list

Tags: javascript

So i want to make a table that i can fill up with info. 
I've managed to fill one cell with a value of a text box. But i can't do the same with drop-down lists.
I've created the list:

```
<select name="status">
<option value="10 perces">10 perces</option>
<option value="ebéd">ebéd</option>
<option value="egyéb">egyéb</option>
</select>
```

And tried to get the value or text:

```
var tstatus = document.getElementById("status");
            var result = tstatus.options[tstatus.selectedIndex].text;

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

I dont know where is the issue, the value extracting code is wrong, or the array filler. 
Full code down below

[Full code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCXD6ZVTIJ4X)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EphYP.png)

Comment: Just change this <select name="status"> to <select id="status"> as var tstatus = document.getElementById("status"); , getElementById accepts id as parameter not name.

Comment: I did it, but still doesn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your using a wrong selector, you should be using:

```
// use querySelector as theres is no element with the id of "status" in your html
var tstatus = document.querySelector("[name='status']");


var result = tstatus.options[tstatus.selectedIndex].text;
// you also need an element to set the inner HTML to
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;

<!-- Updated HTML -->

<select name="status">
  <option value="10 perces">10 perces</option>
  <option value="ebéd">ebéd</option>
  <option value="egyéb">egyéb</option>
</select>

<span id="result"></span>

// Updated Javascript
var tstatus = document.querySelector("[name='status']");

var result = tstatus.options[tstatus.selectedIndex].text;

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Well, it works, but it will write the result outside of the table. How can i write the variable inside that cell? Sorry, im really new into this :D

Comment: So after you select the value, what do you want to happen to the selected option?

Comment: I placed a picture above. 
When i press the button, it will create a new row for me with javascript, and im trying to place the value there.
But when i use your code, it will write the value in the html section of the page, wherever i put it. But i want to place it into that new cell after creation.

Comment: can I see the html element of where you want it to be placed?

Comment: Its not a html element. As i said, i dont want it to be placed in html element. I want it to be placed inside the cell i created in js.

Full code is above on the link.

When i press the button, a new row is created. I want to place the value to the 4th cell in the row.